# How can I change success message font size on Bootstrap Contact form?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, contact-form

On  http://ahepa215.org/contact.html I am using a responsive contact form I saw for Bootstrap. When you submit it gives you a success message from the contact.php page. 
    `$okMessage = 'Contact form successfully submitted. Thank you, I will get back to you soon!';` How can I make that message larger?

```html
<form id="contact-form" method="post" action="contact.php" role="form">
<div class="messages"></div>
<div class="controls">
<div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="form_name">First Name *</label>
                                        <input id="form_name" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your first name *" required="required" data-error="Firstname is required.">
                                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="form_lastname">Last Name *</label>
                                        <input id="form_lastname" type="text" name="surname" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your last name *" required="required" data-error="Lastname is required.">
                                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="form_email">Email *</label>
                                        <input id="form_email" type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your email *" required="required" data-error="Valid email is required.">
                                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="form_phone">Phone</label>
                                        <input id="form_phone" type="tel" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your phone">
                                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="form_message">Message *</label>
                                        <textarea id="form_message" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Message for me *" rows="4" required="required" data-error="Please,leave us a message."></textarea>
                                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-send" value="Send message">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <p class="text-muted"><strong>*</strong> These fields are required.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
</form>
```

This is the entire php code, I couldn't see how to add it in the snippet box;

Comment: sorry it says php code is too long, here is a link to it on mt codepen http://codepen.io/mlegg10/post/php-send

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it in css like this.

```
.messages .alert-success {
    font-size: 30px;

}
```